# LocalStorage not showing with build file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have implemented a small localStorage with react, where I save URI endpoints once the users enters them, and I call them on my componentDidMount function if they exist.

The setup seemed super simple and it totally worked while I was doing npm start on my dev files, however on building my project and hosting it locally using 'serve', I am not able to see my localStorage anymore. Does this have to do something with the build files or the way I'm serving them?

```
componentDidMount() {
  userUri = localStorage.getItem('userUri');
  tracesUri = localStorage.getItem('tracesUri');
  if (userUri && tracesUri) {
    this.setState({
      userUri: userUri,
      tracesUri: tracesUri
    });
  }
};

closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({
    showSettings: false
  });
  localStorage.setItem('userUri', this.state.userUri);
  localStorage.setItem('tracesUri', this.state.tracesUri);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, when you run your app locally, you are not able to see the data that was persisted when you ran your app via `npm`?

Something to keep in mind is that data stored via `localStorage` is restricted to the current `document.origin` [see MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You need to ensure that you are testing/running locally at the same `origin` for the same persisted data to be visible in both cases.

You can add this code to your app:

```
 console.log('Origin is:', document.origin);
```

This will print the origin to console, and then cross check this origin by running the app both via 'npm' and by hosting locally to verify that the origin is the same or different

Answer (score 0):

Access to data stored in the browser such as localStorage and IndexedDB are separated by origin. Each origin gets its own separate storage, and JavaScript in one origin cannot read from or write to the storage belonging to another origin.[ref: [link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

So I guess while you serve, you must be using a different port due to which you were not able to access the previous localStorage values.